# Roman numeral analysis spacing in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I'm doing analysis on a piece and using the [roman-numeral-tool](https://github.com/davidnalesnik/lilypond-roman-numeral-tool) to add the roman numerals.

```
\version "2.20"
\language "italiano"

\include "roman_numeral_analysis_tool.ily"

\header {
 title = \markup { \fontsize #1.5 "An die Musik" }
}

% PIANO UPPER
pianoUpperIntro = \relative do' {
% 1
 <la re fad>8[ <la re fad> <la re fad> <la re fad>] <la re fad>[ <la re fad> <la re fad> <la re fad>]
 <la re la'>[ <la re la'> <la re la'> <la re la'>] <la dod sol'>[ <la dod sol'> <sol la dod mi> <sol la dod mi>]
}

pianoUpper = {
 \clef treble
 \time 2/2
 \key re \major
 \set autoBeaming = ##f
 \pianoUpperIntro
}


analysis = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza  = #"D:"
  % For bare Roman numerals, \rN simply outputs the string.
  \markup \rN { Ic }
  \markup \rN { Ic }
  \markup \rN { Ib }
  \markup \rN { V 7 }
  \markup \rN { Vc 7 }
}

\score {
 <<
  \new PianoStaff <<
      \new Voice = "up" << \pianoUpper >>
    \new Lyrics \with {
    } \lyricsto "up" { \analysis }
  >>
 >>
}
```

But the above code doesn't put the roman numeral on every note - instead every four notes. How do I change that to every note?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

\rN { Ic }8 etc - there are example files in the git repo.